# Google Custom Search API results paging

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I've been seeing some issues with paging of search results, and when investigating using the API explorer (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list)
i am getting significantly different values for "totalResults" simply by changing the "start" value. e.g.

`q=pizza, start=1 -> totalResults=83
q=pizza, start=21 -> totalResults=83
q=pizza, start=31 -> totalResults=33
(All other parameters are default)`

Am I misunderstanding this, or are there any other parameters i need to use to make this work as expected?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've found a number of posts describing the same issue going back to 2009 and the same issue can even be seen performing an actual Google search using the "site:" operator, where it shows e.g. 9 pages of results, but clicking on page 7 returns no results

Comment: did anyone know the fixes? I am also facing the same issue :(

Comment: I finding the same issue. Hard to believe.